# Insert into enum type using IF statement psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im copying data in from a csv file, I want insert a value which depends on if the data in the csv file reads `yes` or `no`

```
CREATE TYPE colour_type as ENUM ('red', 'blue');

CREATE TABLE colour_table
(
 colour colour_type
);

CREATE TABLE Dummy 
 (
  colour_type_dummy varchar(40)
 );
 
 \copy TABLE FROM 'colours.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);

-- This is the part where I cant figure out the syntax for the IF statement
INSERT INTO colour_table (colour)
SELECT 'red' IF colour_type_dummy = 'yes' else 'blue' FROM Dummy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` expression

```
INSERT INTO colour_table (colour)
SELECT CASE WHEN colour_type_dummy = 'yes' THEN 'red'::colour_type ELSE 'blue'::colour_type END
FROM Dummy
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cd5cffb2253d787ed4cbd002207a5e4c)

Comment: thankyou how would I do this to add an IF ELSE statement

Comment: you can't as Postgres has no of then else see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html

Comment: @coderoftheday as nbk say there isn't `if ... else` statement in `SELECT` but we can use `CASE WHEN` instead